# How to change theme in Debian 9 XFCE from pling.com using OCS-Install

Tags: installation, debian, icons, themes, xfce

The default theme is kinda boring, but I prefer Debian because is stable and have the most useful apps and software for me. Also, I like XFCE because of performance and stability, so I am not changing to other WM.

So I tried to Install some themes and icons from [pling](https://www.pling.com) and succeded when they provide a `zip` or tarball, but some of the themes don't have that and just provide an OCS install

[OCS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zNtZ.png)

[Ubuntu-Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0CoV.png)
I did not found a way to install OCS in Debian, just Ubunutu and other, is there a way to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact answer for your question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128098).

I have tested it in a Debian 9 box myself and everything seems to be working.

Post by user [rolf](https://askubuntu.com/users/67745/rolf):

> I installed a few themes from [gnome-look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/)
>
> The site uses a special URL scheme. The URL handler comes in a package
>   named `ocs-url`. Here are the [instructions for installing the URL
>   handler on linux-apps.com](https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1136805/).
>
> However, the installation method described on this site has an issue:
>   it marks the dependencies as manually installed.
>
> Therefore I recommend the following method instead.
>
> My method will ensure that, when you uninstall ocs-url, its
>   dependencies will be automatically uninstalled as well.
>
> First download the `ocs-url` Debian package, then (filename and
>   directory name might differ):
>
> ```
> cd ~/Downloads
> sudo dpkg -i ocs-url_3.1.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
> sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
> ```
>
> Once this is done, all you have to do is click on install links on
>   gnome-look.org and them click "OK" and the themes will be installed in
>   `~/.themes`.
>
> Restart the Tweaks tool and your new themes should be available.
>
> Tested on Debian.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!